# CSS grid on iOS using variable width is breaking. Why?

Tags: html, ios, css

[image: That's how it should look.]

That's how it should look.

[image: That's how it does look.]

That's how it does look.

The same works fine on Android phones but breaks on iOS and only on the first load. If I refresh the page, it settles into the correct thing.

This is the code in handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>{{link_data.workplace.name}} - A Super Workplace!</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://admin.getsuperapp.com/public/superfavicon.ico">

    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

    <style>
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,400italic);

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .content {
        padding-bottom: 62px;
    }

    .content .cover {
    }

    .cover img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content .name-logo {
        padding-left: 6.79%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
    }

    .content .name-logo .logo {
        width: 58px;
        height: 58px;
        border-color: #d8d8d8;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        position: relative;
        background: #fff;
    }

    .content .name-logo .logo img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .content .name-logo .join-us {
        width: 70%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 4px;
        font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        color: rgba(55, 71, 79, 0.54);
    }

    .content .name-logo .join-us .text {
        font-size: 8pt;
    }

    .content .name-logo .join-us .company-name {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #37474f;
        font-size: 16pt;
    }

    .content .company-headline {
        font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        line-height: 16pt;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 6.79%;
        padding-right: 6.79%;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
    }

    .content .people-carousel {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #87A0AD ;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content .people-carousel.collapsed {
        height: 136px;
    }

    .content .people-carousel .person {
        width: 33.53vw;
        height: 33.33vw;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 -2px -4px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content .people-carousel .person img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content .next-person {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40.3px;
        background-color: #03A9F4;
    }

    .content .next-person .text {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 14pt;
        line-height: 18pt;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .content .next-person .you {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24pt;
        line-height: 24pt;
        color: #ffeb3b;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .content .get-app {
        background-color: #37474f;

        position: fixed;
        bottom: -1px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .content .get-app .badge {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 14px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 32px;
    }

    .content .get-app .badge img {
        width: auto;
        height: 36px;
    }

    .content .get-app .button-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 46vw;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: right;
        right: 26px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .content .get-app .button-wrapper a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .content .get-app .button {
        width: 120px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #FFEB3B;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        border-radius: 4.4px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: -25px;
    }

    .content .get-app .button .button-text {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 0.3px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 11px;
    }

    .page-not-found {
        width: 300;
        height: 300;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #BCBCCA;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .page-not-found .text {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 100;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
{{#if link_data.enabled}}
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
    <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_30,w_1242,e_blur:90/{{link_data.workplace.coverImage.cloudinaryId}}"
             alt="Banner"/>
    </div>

    <div class="name-logo">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/w_230/{{link_data.workplace.logo.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="logo"/>
        </div>

        <div class="join-us">
            <span class="text">Come join us at</span> <br/>
            <span class="company-name">{{link_data.workplace.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="company-headline">
        {{link_data.workplace.headline}}...
    </div>

    <div class="people-carousel {{#unless link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.4.image}}collapsed{{/unless}}">
        <div class="person">
            {{#if link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.0.image}}
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_70,w_380,e_blur:20/{{link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.0.image.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="person"/>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <div class="person">
            {{#if link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.1.image}}
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_70,w_380,e_blur:20/{{link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.1.image.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="person"/>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <div class="person">
            {{#if link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.2.image}}
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_70,w_380,e_blur:20/{{link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.2.image.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="person"/>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <div class="person">
            {{#if link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.3.image}}
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_70,w_380,e_blur:20/{{link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.3.image.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="person"/>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <div class="person">
            {{#if link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.4.image}}
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_70,w_380,e_blur:20/{{link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.4.image.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="person"/>
            {{/if}}
        </div>

        <div class="person">
            {{#if link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.5.image}}
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/q_70,w_380,e_blur:20/{{link_data.workplace.peopleCarousel.5.image.cloudinaryId}}"
                 alt="person"/>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="next-person">
        <div class="text">
            Will the next person <br/>
            to join {{link_data.workplace.name}} be
        </div>

        <div class="you">
            you?
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="get-app">
        <div class="badge">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/superapp/image/upload/v1453184144/super-badge-ios_3x_x1zdix.png"
                 alt="badge"/>
        </div>

        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <a href="{{action}}">
                <div class="button">
                    <div class="button-text">
                        Get the App
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <div class="page-not-found">
        <div class="text">
            Page Not Found!
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your codes dont find device

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when things are fixed when you reload the page, the problem is that an `img` isn't loaded at the time the styles are applied, so the rendered doesn't know the width/height of an element and gets the layout wrong, you have to force the layout to your needs.

- Try setting a fixed `width` and `height` for the `img` tags.
- Try setting `vertical-align:bottom` to all the `img` and `.person`
- Try setting `overflow:hidden` on `.person`

I'm not sure if all of these would work, but I hope at least one will.